# Docker container connect to host DocumentDB emulator

Tags: docker, emulation, azure-cosmosdb

I have a `.NET core` application and I'd like to connect to an instance of `DocumentDB` emulator available on host using the `Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Client.1.2.1` NuGet package.

The address of the host is `10.0.75.1`, therefore I'm using the Uri `https://10.0.75.1:8181`.

During initialisation I'm getting the following exception: `System.Net.Http.CurlException: SSL peer certificate or SSH remote key was not OK`.

I've tried to copy the `pem` certificate of the emulator to `container:/usr/share/ca-certificates` and run the `update-ca-certificates` command without success.

Any suggestion?